# Export to Excel with a hyperlink field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-excel, js-xlsx

I am exporting some data to excel as follows :-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

export const ExportCSV = ({csvData, fileName}) => {

    const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    const fileExtension = '.xlsx';

    const exportToCSV = (csvData, fileName) => {
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(csvData);
        const wb = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
        const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
        const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], {type: fileType});
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
    }

    return (
        <a onClick={ (e) => exportToCSV(csvData,fileName)}>Export Tasks To Excel</a>
    )
}

export default ExportCSV;
```

Now I would like to have one of the fields as a hyperlink, so that when the user opens the Excel sheet, he/she can click on the hyperlink and get redirected to that site.

Is it possible with this component?  Anybody has done anything similar?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you can populate your fields in your CSV file like this :

> "=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE(""http://www.google.com"";""Google"")"
>
> or
>
> "=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"";""Google"")"

This will create hyperlinks.

Comment: Hi @L.G do you mean something like this?             let urlLink = '=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"";""Google"")';
This did not work

Comment: I also tried             let urlLink = '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com")';
but it literally wrote  '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com")'.  Should be converted to a function

Comment: I mean exactly this format of quotes : "=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"";""Google"")"

Comment: As CSV file fields, you can format your field like this with fewer quotes : HYPERLINK=("http://www.google.com")

Comment: `"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"";""Google"")"` throws a SyntaxError when trying it out to console, did you mean to escape those quote marks? Like this: `"=HYPERLINK(\"http://www.google.com\";\"Google\")"`? I've suggested an edit with your code.

Comment: I try it with a CSV file example and open it with Excel and it works with double quotes. That's what he does in his code, he creates a CSV file, here is my CSV file :`num;link
123;"=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE(""http://www.google.com"";""Google"")"`